# Getting an error of 'Token Unknown' while Execute Stored Procedures

Tags: firebird, flamerobin

I'm new in learning stored procedures in **SQL**.

I want to create a stored procedure for inserting values from automatic data by calculation.

Table `Attendance`:

```
EMPL_KODE |EMPL_NAME  |DATE_IN    |TIME_IN |TIME_OUT|TIME_IN |TIME_OUT
001       | Michel    |25.04.2016 |06:50   |15:40   |        |
002       | Clara     |25.04.2016 |06:15   |15:43   |        |
003       | Rafael    |25.04.2016 |06:25   |15:45   |        |
001       | Michel    |26.04.2016 |06:23   |15:42   |        |
002       | Clara     |26.04.2016 |06:10   |15:41   |        |
003       | Rafael    |26.04.2016 |06:30   |15:42   |        |
001       | Michel    |27.04.2016 |06:33   |15:42   |        |
002       | Clara     |27.04.2016 |06:54   |15:44   |        |
003       | Rafael    |27.04.2016 |07:00   |15:45   |        |
```

I want to fill `TIME_IN` and `TIME_OUT` values automatically by creating a stored procedure. Here is the code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTotalEmployee
    @TOTAL_MINUTES int,
    @TOTAL_HOURS float
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE (TOTAL_MINUTES, TOTAL_HOURS)
    VALUES (
       SELECT 
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ATTENDANCE.TIME_IN, ATTENDANCE.TIME_OUT),
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ATTENDANCE.TIME_IN, ATTENDANCE.TIME_OUT) / 60.0
    )
END
```

After I write and execute my statement, a message error occurs:

> Token unknown - line 2, column 5 @

I run the code using Flamerobin.

Comment: Also: you have a consistent typo - it's **attendance** (and not "attadence" as you keep spelling it)

Comment: @marc_s I'm sorry for mistake that i made. Thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use Microsoft SQL Server syntax in Firebird, that is not going to work.

For one, the `@` is not allowed like that in identifiers (unless you use double quotes around them), and the list of parameters must be enclosed in parentheses.

See the syntax of [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-proc-create). You need to change it to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTotalEmployee(TOTAL_MINUTES int, TOTAL_HOURS float)
```

You also might want to change the datatype `float` to `double precision`, and the body of your stored procedure seems to be incomplete because you are selecting from nothing (a `select` requires a table to select from), and are missing a semicolon at the end of the statement.

All in all I suggest you study the [Firebird language reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html), then try to create a functioning insert and only then create a stored procedure around it.

Also note that when creating a stored procedure in Flamerobin, that you must switch statement terminators using `set term` otherwise Flamerobin can't send the stored procedure correctly, see also the first section in [Procedural SQL (PSQL) Statements](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql).

Comment: thanks to give me explanation. but, i'm still confused about input and output parameter. and also about declare variable.

Comment: It is explained in the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql.html), and otherwise you should ask a new, specific question.